# difference between get + adjective and grow + adjective

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentences  :

> The passengers grew angry about the delay.
>
> The passengers got angry about the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The passengers **grew angry** about the delay.

Here the level of *anger* is a changing state. As time went by they got angrier and angrier.

> The passengers **got angry** about the delay.

This statement was made after the fact, and only says that in the end they were angry. But we can't tell how angry that is.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that to grow + adjective or past participle describes a slow gradual change. Typical example: to grow old.

"to get" only expresses a change without information whether the process is fast or slow. It is the normal verb for the get-passive as in: They got killed in an accident.

For quick changes "to turn" is often used as in: She turned red.